# Parallel pooling warning in MATLAB

Tags: multithreading, matlab, parallel-processing, deep-learning

While executing the following program in MATLAB, I got a warning telling me that 3 workers in the parallel pool cannot be assigned to their GPU and will be unused. Does anybody have an idea about what can be the solution for using all the workers?

---

```
imds = imageDatastore('YOUR DATABASE ADDRESS', 'IncludeSubfolders',true, 
'LabelSource', 'foldernames');

net = alexnet();

[trainingSet, testSet] = splitEachLabel(imds, 0.3, 'randomize');
layersTransfer = net.Layers(1:end-3);
numClasses = numel(categories(trainingSet.Labels));

layers = [...
layersTransfer
fullyConnectedLayer(numClasses,'WeightLearnRateFactor',20,
'BiasLearnRateFactor',20)
softmaxLayer
classificationLayer];

options = 
trainingOptions('sgdm','InitialLearnRate',0.001,'ExecutionEnvironment',
'parallel');

netTransfer = trainNetwork(trainingSet,layers,options);
```

---

This is the warning I got:

```
Warning: 3 workers in the parallel pool cannot be assigned their own GPU and 
will be unused. When configuring the cluster, ensure only one worker per GPU 
is running on each node. 

In trainNetwork>iValidateWorkerLoad (line 499)
In trainNetwork>iSetupAndValidateParallel (line 368)
In trainNetwork>iSetupExecutionEnvironment (line 354)
In trainNetwork (line 77)
```

and this is my system information:

CPU: Core i7
Graphic Card: Gforce GT 640.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [documentation for `trainingOptions`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/trainingoptions.html#input_argument_d0e59903), when you're using `'parallel'` execution mode, `trainNetwork` uses as many workers as you have GPU devices in your system (unless there are no GPU devices, in which case it uses the CPU). The only way to use more workers is to install more GPU devices.

Comment: Thanks for your comment...Actually you are right...I was not aware of the fact that each worker is assigned to one GPU.